# Directly calculating conditional averages in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I ‘m guessing there is a better method to go about avergaing a dict in Python, but I’m unsure how to go about it.  At the moment I have a dict of dicts and I am trying to find a better method of finding say the average age of company car owners in a company.  At the moment I am getting a correct result but I think my method is inefficient, as I would search each NAME key in the Company dict, check for Company Car == to ‘Yes’ and then drop the age of the employee into a list, I would then do an average calculation on the list at the end of the Company dict.  I am sure there must be a better method than creating lists and dropping values into it?

Here’s an example on my dict of dicts…

```
Company{

'NAME1': {''M_or_F': 'Male',
              'AGE’: '24',
             ‘DEPT’: ‘Finance',
      ‘Company Car’:’No’'}

'NAME2': {''M_or_F': 'Male',
              'AGE’: '52',
             ‘DEPT’: ‘Marketing',
      ‘Company Car’:’Yes’'}

'NAME3': {''M_or_F': 'Female',
              'AGE’: '36',
             ‘DEPT’: ‘Finance',
      ‘Company Car’:'Yes''}

'NAME4': {''M_or_F': 'Male',
              'AGE’: '28',
             ‘DEPT’: ‘Finance',
      ‘Company Car’:’No’'}

'NAME5': {''M_or_F': 'Female',
              'AGE’: '23',
             ‘DEPT’: ‘HR',
      ‘Company Car’:’Yes’'}
}
```

Any hints on how I could do away with lists and calculate directly from the dictionary?

My current inefficient method is …

```
CC_agelist = []

for NAME in Company:
    if (Company[NAME][‘Company Car'] == 'Yes'):
        CC_agelist.append(int(Company[NAME]['AGE’]))

 #followed by an average calculation on CC_agelist
```

Comment: Please fix the quotes in your program. It makes it unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, clean up the syntax of your data as follows:

```
Company = {

'NAME1': {'M_or_F': 'Male',
             'AGE': '24',
            'DEPT': 'Finance',
     'Company Car': 'No'},

'NAME2': {'M_or_F': 'Male',
             'AGE': '52',
            'DEPT': 'Marketing',
     'Company Car': 'Yes'},

'NAME3': {'M_or_F': 'Female',
             'AGE': '36',
            'DEPT': 'Finance',
     'Company Car': 'Yes'},

'NAME4': {'M_or_F': 'Male',
             'AGE': '28',
            'DEPT': 'Finance',
     'Company Car': 'No'},

'NAME5': {'M_or_F': 'Female',
             'AGE': '23',
            'DEPT': 'HR',
     'Company Car': 'Yes'}
}
```

Now you can use a list comprehension to get your list, followed by a simple formula for calculating the mean:

```
CC_agelist = [int(D['AGE']) for D in Company.itervalues() if D['Company Car'] == 'Yes']
mean_CC_age = float(sum(CC_agelist)) / len(CC_agelist)
```

Or you can import numpy and do everything on one line:

```
import numpy as np
mean_CC_age = np.mean([int(D['AGE']) for D in Company.itervalues() if D['Company Car'] == 'Yes'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this looks much cleaner